# On click of a element under data-rel popup , how can i fetch its id

Tags: jquery

On click of a element under  data-rel popup , how can i fetch its  id taht is (addonsWrap in my case )

I have tried as , but

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function (e) {
    $elem = $(this);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/91/

Could you please let em know how to resolve this , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-content').attr('id');
```

#### [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/92/)